# Redirecting with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to redirect to another page within my view with HAML, depending on the state of a variable.

**Ideal situation:**

```
- if days < 1
     - redirect to /settings
```

Comment: Why would you do that? You should be handling redirecting in the controller.

Comment: agree with @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff you should handle these things in controller itself as you are getting `days` variable from controller

Comment: Okie dokie, noob mistake. Answered my own question via your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Don't handle redirects through your views, use your controller.

**Controller:**

```
if days > 1
    redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
end
```